# On Click function not behaving as expected; confused as to why? (Android Studio, RecyclerView)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Ok I've been pondering this all weekend and I'm running in circles and confusing myself about it; so someone please help. Here's the scoop: I have an app with a RecyclerView to hold CardView items. Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scene_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#75757A">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/listItemWrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/assetSymbol"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="SYM"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold">
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/assetPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/assetSymbol"
            android:text="$1,000.00"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/assetSymbol">
        </TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="30sp"
            android:layout_height="30sp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/assetPrice"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/assetPrice">
        </ImageView>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/openShort"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/assetPrice"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/bearRed"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bear_enter" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/openLong"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/assetPrice"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/openShort"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/openShort"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/bullGreen"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bull_enter" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/deleteAsset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/assetPrice"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/openLong"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/openLong"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_delete_asset" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/editAsset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/assetPrice"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/deleteAsset"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/deleteAsset"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_edit_asset" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/showOptions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_more_vert" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

You'll notice that the card contains four floating action buttons, which are initially hidden. What I'm trying to do is have the buttons animate into view when the user clicks the "show options" ImageView (android:id="@+id/showOptions"). Here is all the relevant code snippets:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private ArrayList<WatchListItem> watchListArray;
    private RecyclerView watchList;
    private WatchListAdapter listAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager listManager;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        watchListArray = new ArrayList<>();
        watchList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.watchList);
        watchList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        listManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        watchList.setLayoutManager(listManager);
        listAdapter = new WatchListAdapter(watchListArray);
        watchList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    public void engage(Asset asset) {
        int position = watchListArray.size();
        String ticker = asset.getSymbol();
        //Double.toString(asset.getCurrentPrice()) replaced with fixed value for testing
        String price = "390.55";
        //int indicator set to fixed value for testing
        int indicator = R.drawable.ic_bull_indicator;
        watchListArray.add(position, new WatchListItem(indicator, price, ticker));
        listAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
        listAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new WatchListAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShowOptionsClick(int position, ImageView show, FloatingActionButton edit, FloatingActionButton delete, FloatingActionButton oLong, FloatingActionButton oShort) {
                expandListItem(position, show, edit, delete, oLong, oShort);
            }
        });
    }

    public void expandListItem(int position, ImageView show, FloatingActionButton edit, FloatingActionButton delete, FloatingActionButton oLong, FloatingActionButton oShort) {
        if (edit.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            show.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_collapse);
            oShort.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(150);
            oLong.animate().alpha(1f).setStartDelay(125).setDuration(150);
            delete.animate().alpha(1f).setStartDelay(250).setDuration(150);
            edit.animate().alpha(1f).setStartDelay(375).setDuration(150);
        } else {
            edit.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(150);
            delete.animate().alpha(0f).setStartDelay(125).setDuration(150);
            oLong.animate().alpha(0f).setStartDelay(250).setDuration(150);
            oShort.animate().alpha(0f).setStartDelay(375).setDuration(150);
            show.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_more_vert);
        }
        listAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
```

**WatchListAdapter.java**

```
public class WatchListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WatchListAdapter.WatchListViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<WatchListItem> mWatchList;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onShowOptionsClick(int position, ImageView show, FloatingActionButton edit, FloatingActionButton delete, FloatingActionButton oLong, FloatingActionButton oShort);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public static class WatchListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mAssetSymbol;
        public TextView mAssetPrice;
        public ImageView mImageView;
        public ImageView mShowOptions;
        public FloatingActionButton mEditAsset;
        public FloatingActionButton mDeleteAsset;
        public FloatingActionButton mOpenLong;
        public FloatingActionButton mOpenShort;

        public WatchListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
            mAssetSymbol = itemView.findViewById(R.id.assetSymbol);
            mAssetPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.assetPrice);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            mShowOptions = itemView.findViewById(R.id.showOptions);
            mEditAsset = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editAsset);
            mDeleteAsset = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteAsset);
            mOpenLong = itemView.findViewById(R.id.openLong);
            mOpenShort = itemView.findViewById(R.id.openShort);

            mShowOptions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        ImageView show = mShowOptions;
                        FloatingActionButton edit = mEditAsset;
                        FloatingActionButton delete = mDeleteAsset;
                        FloatingActionButton oLong = mOpenLong;
                        FloatingActionButton oShort = mOpenShort;
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onShowOptionsClick(position, show, edit, delete, oLong, oShort);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public WatchListAdapter(ArrayList<WatchListItem> watchListArray) {
        mWatchList = watchListArray;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public WatchListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new WatchListViewHolder(v, mListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WatchListViewHolder holder, int position) {
        WatchListItem currentItem = mWatchList.get(position);
        holder.mAssetSymbol.setText(currentItem.getAssetSymbol());
        holder.mAssetPrice.setText(currentItem.getAssetPrice());
        holder.mImageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mWatchList.size();
    }
}
```

**WatchListItem.java**

```
public class WatchListItem {
    private int mImageResource;
    private String mAssetPrice;
    private String mAssetSymbol;

    public WatchListItem(int imageResource, String assetPrice, String assetSymbol) {
        mImageResource = imageResource;
        mAssetPrice = assetPrice;
        mAssetSymbol = assetSymbol;
    }

    public int getImageResource() {
        return mImageResource;
    }

    public String getAssetPrice() {
        return mAssetPrice;
    }

    public String getAssetSymbol() {
        return mAssetSymbol;
    }
}
```

*Quick note about the placement of listAdapter.setOnItemClickListener in MainActivity.java: initially this was included in the onCreate() method because that is where the RecyclerView is built and also where it was placed in the tutorial I was trying to follow; but I moved it to the engage() method because this is where the list item is added and I figured it didn't make sense to set the listener before the item even existed, right? Anyway let me know if this is incorrect, as I suspect it is, though regardless this did not change the behavior in testing*
So here's the problem: App opens just fine, adds the item to the RecyclerView, but when I click the dropdown ImageView, nothing. Well not exactly nothing, I can tell it's trying to do something, but ultimately nothing happens. The best way I can describe it is that the CardView kind of "flashes" and the ImageView icon is briefly changed to the new icon but instantly changes back, and that's it. No errors, no crashes; just not performing the specified action and I cannot figure out why. I don't know why they had to deprecate ListView because this all would be a lot less confusing to me if I didn't have to build the onClickListener interface from scratch, but I digress. Thank you so much for taking the time to read all this and offering your valuable input.

Comment: First of all, I'd set the listener on the onCreate method. Even if no items are added, the listener will be ready for when they are added.

Also, when is the "engage" method being called?

Comment: Try removed `listAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);` in _expandListItem()_ which makes the **adapter to redraw the item view with default layout**. In addition, your data set has nothing to indicate an item is expanded, so expanded item will collapse after scrolling.

Comment: Show options icon is changed which tells you _expandListItem()_ is executed and entered the if-condition. FABs not shown should related to your animation, so try add **setVisibility()** for FABs. listAdapter.setOnItemClickListener can be placed inside onCreate() but why not doing in the adapter. The actions that you are doing have nothing related to Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code, see if it helps. I've changed some code in both files. You're now not creating a new listener every time an item is added, which might help.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private ArrayList<WatchListItem> watchListArray;
    private RecyclerView watchList;
    private WatchListAdapter listAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager listManager;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        watchListArray = new ArrayList<>();
        watchList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.watchList);
        watchList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        listManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        watchList.setLayoutManager(listManager);
        listAdapter = new WatchListAdapter(watchListArray);
        listAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new WatchListAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShowOptionsClick(int position, ImageView show, FloatingActionButton edit, FloatingActionButton delete, FloatingActionButton oLong, FloatingActionButton oShort) {
                expandListItem(position, show, edit, delete, oLong, oShort);
            }
        });
        watchList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    public void engage(Asset asset) {
        int position = watchListArray.size();
        String ticker = asset.getSymbol();
        //Double.toString(asset.getCurrentPrice()) replaced with fixed value for testing
        String price = "390.55";
        //int indicator set to fixed value for testing
        int indicator = R.drawable.ic_bull_indicator;
        watchListArray.add(position, new WatchListItem(indicator, price, ticker));
        listAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public void expandListItem(int position, ImageView show, FloatingActionButton edit, FloatingActionButton delete, FloatingActionButton oLong, FloatingActionButton oShort) {
        if (edit.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            show.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_collapse);
            oShort.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(150);
            oLong.animate().alpha(1f).setStartDelay(125).setDuration(150);
            delete.animate().alpha(1f).setStartDelay(250).setDuration(150);
            edit.animate().alpha(1f).setStartDelay(375).setDuration(150);
        } else {
            edit.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(150);
            delete.animate().alpha(0f).setStartDelay(125).setDuration(150);
            oLong.animate().alpha(0f).setStartDelay(250).setDuration(150);
            oShort.animate().alpha(0f).setStartDelay(375).setDuration(150);
            show.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_more_vert);
        }
        listAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
}
```

**WatchListAdapter.java**

```
public class WatchListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WatchListAdapter.WatchListViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<WatchListItem> mWatchList;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onShowOptionsClick(int position, ImageView show, FloatingActionButton edit, FloatingActionButton delete, FloatingActionButton oLong, FloatingActionButton oShort);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public static class WatchListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mAssetSymbol;
        public TextView mAssetPrice;
        public ImageView mImageView;
        public ImageView mShowOptions;
        public FloatingActionButton mEditAsset;
        public FloatingActionButton mDeleteAsset;
        public FloatingActionButton mOpenLong;
        public FloatingActionButton mOpenShort;

        public WatchListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
            mAssetSymbol = itemView.findViewById(R.id.assetSymbol);
            mAssetPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.assetPrice);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            mShowOptions = itemView.findViewById(R.id.showOptions);
            mEditAsset = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editAsset);
            mDeleteAsset = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteAsset);
            mOpenLong = itemView.findViewById(R.id.openLong);
            mOpenShort = itemView.findViewById(R.id.openShort);
        }
    }

    public WatchListAdapter(ArrayList<WatchListItem> watchListArray) {
        mWatchList = watchListArray;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public WatchListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new WatchListViewHolder(v, mListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WatchListViewHolder holder, int position) {
        WatchListItem currentItem = mWatchList.get(position);
        holder.mAssetSymbol.setText(currentItem.getAssetSymbol());
        holder.mAssetPrice.setText(currentItem.getAssetPrice());
        holder.mImageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());
        holder.mShowOptions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    ImageView show = holder.mShowOptions;
                    FloatingActionButton edit = holder.mEditAsset;
                    FloatingActionButton delete = holder.mDeleteAsset;
                    FloatingActionButton oLong = holder.mOpenLong;
                    FloatingActionButton oShort = holder.mOpenShort;
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        listener.onShowOptionsClick(position, show, edit, delete, oLong, oShort);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mWatchList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you Iscle for the suggestions. I modified my code accordingly, with a few extra adjustments of my own. For those who may reference this question later: "listener" was not defined in the onBindViewHolder, but this was fixed by simply adding an accessor method to WatchListAdapter. Unfortunately, after these changes were made, the problem persisted. It was, however, improved slightly per another commenter who suggested removing ```listAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);```. With this line removed, the show options icon is changed, but the floating action buttons still won't fadeIn

Comment: Also as a side note to Iscle, to answer your question about the engage() method: Basically, when the app opens the RecyclerView is visible on the main screen along with a FAB to add new items to the list. Tapping this button inflates a popup window, where the user inputs the relevant info and then clicks an "add to list" button. It is on this button click that engage() is called. I did not include this code with my submission because I did not deem it relevant to this issue and did not want to make people read a bunch of superfluous code

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Thank you to all who took the time to answer, especially to i_A_mok whose suggestion ultimately led to the fix. The code I had was perfectly sufficient; I only needed to add setVisibilty(View.VISIBLE) to each FAB before animating the alpha property. For some reason, I believed that by transitioning from alpha 0.0 to alpha 1.0 would automatically make the view visible, but alas this is not the case: visibility and alpha are two separate properties and need to be set independently.